# How to make custom rule for redrawing elements in v-for?

Tags: vue.js

For example I have `scenes` array drawn in `v-for`. If I change the first element of `scenes` Vue will redraw each element of `scenes` and if those elements are objects - each field will be redrawn as well.

My `v-for`:

```
<div
   class="scene"
   v-for="scene of scenes"
   :key="scene"
>
   <p>{{scene.name}}</p>
   <iframe
      style="border: 0"
      :src="scene.frameURL"
   ></iframe>
</div>
```

In my case each `scene` element contains data to load specific page with iframe and also to show it's name. And now if I change some scene's name - each another scene objects will be redrawn and iframe pages will be reloaded.

How to tell Vue to redraw only field's been changed and to not touch another fields and elements?

Comment: One of the best benefits of Vue is that you *don't* have to tell it when to redraw, it'll figure that out on it's own (unless it falls into one of a [few caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)).

Comment: Also relevant here from the Vue.js Guide: [List Rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), [Array Change Detection](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection), and especially [Maintaining State (ie. keys)](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State).

Comment: @zcoop98 actually my question is how to prevent the redrawing of each element and redraw only elements been changed and set transition clip on it.

Comment: Definitely check out that maintaining state link them. I think the `key` attribute will be the answer to the redraw concern. I'm not experienced with transitions, but there's a full [section of the Vue.js guide on them](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html).